# Pass an ArrayList into a Response class method upon form submission in Java web app (JAX RS, Jersey)

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, arraylist

I'm trying to make a web app version of a Java program I wrote, using Java JAX RS and Tomcat.

I wrote a .java service for uploading CSV files and performing some data operations on them which results in an ArrayList. After the users upload their first .csv file they proceed to another web page, where they need to upload a 2nd .csv file.

A very similar `Reponse` class service is used for this 2nd file upload. The difference is that to do the data operations on the 2nd file, I need the ArrayList that was created by the first Java file associated with the prior CSV upload page. I'm not sure how to get that data into this service.

The HTML in question is simply

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head ng-cloak>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laureate SilverBullet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-cloak ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>Upload Prediction (Scoring) Data</h1>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

    <form action="../services/upload/csv_scoring" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        <input type="file" name="file" size="45" accept=".csv"/>
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Score"  class="file-upload-button" />
    </form>
```

and what I have so far for the 2nd service is (skipping the `import` statements):

```
@Path("/upload")
public class UploadFileServiceScoring 
{
    @POST
    @Path("/csv_scoring")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response uploadCsvFile(  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
    //public ArrayList uploadCsvFile(  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,          
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception {
        String UPLOAD_PATH = "D:/sb_user_uploads/";
        try {
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH + fileMetaData.getFileName()));
            while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            String filelocation = new String(UPLOAD_PATH + fileMetaData.getFileName());

            String[] csvarff = new String[2];
            csvarff[0] = filelocation;
            csvarff[1] = "datafile_scoring.arff";
            CSV2Arff.main(csvarff); 

            BufferedReader datafile = null; 
            Instances test = null;

            datafile = readDataFile.readDataFile("datafile_scoring.arff");
            test = new Instances(datafile);
            // need first ArrayList here!!
```

Comment: For what do you need response from first method?

Comment: @aggredi Do you mean why do I need the ArrayList from the first method in this 2nd one? It's because this 2nd method is doing predictions on new data (the 2nd CSV) using a Machine Learning statistical model created in the 1st method. The ArrayList has the Machine Learning model in it. The 1st CSV file was the "training" data set for the ML model and the 2nd CSV file is the "prediction" data set.

Comment: I think you should use database to store results. Or EJB has stateful beans but in this case you should use application server.

Comment: @aggredi That sounds good, but I'm not sure how I can write a Machine Learning model to a database or file. The model itself is of class `classifier` from the `WEKA` ML library. There must be some way to do it though. I don't know much about beans; I will look into that as a possible solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing out the `ArrayList` as an I/O file in the first script:

```
    String ioFile = "temp.dat";
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream =
            new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(ioFile));
        outputStream.writeObject(al1);
        outputStream.close();
    }

    catch ( IOException e ){
        System.out.println("Error writing to file " + ioFile);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Then reading it back in within the 2nd service:

```
        String ioFile = "temp.dat";
        ArrayList al1 = null; //        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        try{
            ObjectInputStream inputStream =
                    new ObjectInputStream(
                            new FileInputStream (ioFile));
            al1 = (ArrayList)inputStream.readObject(); 
            inputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully read the file " + ioFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Problem reading the file " + ioFile);
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

If there's a better solution, such as one that avoids writing to disk and thereby creating another copy of the object, please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.